# How to define name for the prisma relations

Tags: orm, relationship, prisma

I want to understand why we need to define the name of the relation. is this necessary or not in Prisma,
Is there any other standard way to define the name of the relations?

In the below example, I have defined some names for the relations. can you tell me your idea to define the standard name for relations

```
model User {
  id         Int     @unique @default(autoincrement()) @db.Integer
  first_name String  @db.VarChar(75)
  last_name  String? @db.VarChar(75)
  email      String  @db.VarChar(100)
  mobile_no  String? @db.VarChar(15)
  role_id    Int     @db.Integer
  role       Role    @relation(fields: [role_id], references: [id])

  otp                       String?   @db.VarChar(4)

  encrypted_password String? @db.Text
  access_token       String? @db.Text

  sign_in_count      Int       @default(0) @db.Integer()
  current_sign_in_ip String?   @db.VarChar(50)
  last_sign_in_ip    String?   @db.VarChar(50)
  current_sign_in_at DateTime? @db.Timestamp()
  last_sign_in_at    DateTime? @db.Timestamp()

  created_by           Int?  @db.Integer
  create_user_relation User? @relation(name: "created_by_user", fields: [created_by], references: [id])
  updated_by           Int?  @db.Integer
  update_user_relation User? @relation(name: "updated_by_user", fields: [updated_by], references: [id])

  created_at DateTime  @default(now()) @db.Timestamp()
  updated_at DateTime  @default(now()) @updatedAt
  deleted_at DateTime? @db.Timestamp()

  created_by_user User[] @relation("created_by_user")
  updated_by_user User[] @relation("updated_by_user")
  created_by_book Book[] @relation("created_by_book")
  updated_by_book Book[] @relation("updated_by_book")

  @@index([id, first_name, last_name, email])
  @@map("users")
}
```

```
model Book {
  id          Int      @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name        String   @db.VarChar(100)
  author      String   @db.VarChar(100)
  rating      Decimal? @db.Decimal(2, 1)
  price       Int      @db.Integer
  category_id Int      @db.Integer
  description String?  @db.VarChar()

  create_book_relation User  @relation(name: "created_by_book", fields: [created_by], references: [id])
  created_by           Int   @db.Integer
  update_book_relation User? @relation(name: "updated_by_book", fields: [updated_by], references: [id])
  updated_by           Int?  @db.Integer

  created_at DateTime  @db.Timestamp()
  updated_at DateTime  @updatedAt
  deleted_at DateTime? @db.Timestamp()

  @@index([id, name, author, price])
  @@map("books")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The prisma documentation gives a quite good hint, when/why it is necessary to specify a name:

> When you define two relations between two the same models, you need to add the name argument in the @relation attribute to disambiguate them.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#disambiguating-relations

How to name the relation is a quite opinionated. Not the right kind of question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @some-user, you have to disambiguate them somehow, as shown in [the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/data-model/relations#disambiguating-relations):

```
model User {
  id           Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String?
  writtenPosts Post[]  @relation("WrittenPosts")
  pinnedPost   Post?   @relation("PinnedPost")
}

model Post {
  id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title      String?
  author     User    @relation("WrittenPosts", fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId   Int
  pinnedBy   User?   @relation("PinnedPost", fields: [pinnedById], references: [id])
  pinnedById Int?    @unique
}
```